# Dashboard with total number of items

Tags: sharepoint-online, dashboard

I would like to display how many Documents from a library we have, how many passwords we have in a custom list etc

How would I extract that information and display it look the screenshot below?

I am using SP2013 in Office 365

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways would be to use JSOM or REST with a content editor web part.

To get the count, for instance in JSOM, you would load the list and read ItemCount (mostly via list.get_count()).

Then you could display it using simple HTML+jQuery on the page.